# Command to locate a given directory

Tags: java, unix, directory, command

Is there any (unix) command that can locate a given directory?

So for instance, I have a directory named "MyDir", but I don't know its absolute path on disk. Is there any command that I will give the path to MyDir?

More specifically, I'd like to do this in a Java program (via system call).

```
// return the full path to the specified directory
// if there's more than once directory with the given name
// just return the first one.
static String findPath (String dirName)
{
     // CODE here

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `locate` command, if available (some systems may not have building its index enabled), will perform a substring match against the paths of files in all world-readable directories on the system.

Answer (score 1):

If it's Unix only, you could use the [`locate`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_%28Unix%29) command. Don't forget to run `updatedb` periodically, though (preferably, automatically).

To actually run a command-line command in Java, check out [this article](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016). The basic command is `Runtime#exec`, but you'll want to do some error checking. The snippet provided in the article is:

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaRunCommand {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s = null;

        try {

        // run the Unix "ps -ef" command
            // using the Runtime exec method:
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -ef");

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            // read any errors from the attempted command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you could [Walk the File Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) (Java native using NIO.2). This would probably take longer, though, since it's not cached.

Comment: Uhm, I might've chosen a wrong word that gave a wrong impression about what I wanted to do. As I looked at the manual for `locate`, and it seems to find things out of some database. But my program needs to run without depending on any database. Just imagine when you open a search windows (on Windows, or a Finder on the Mac OS) and do a search.

Comment: The locate database is one that might be maintained by your sysadmin (via the aforementioned updatedb command).  It's a database that reflects the filesystem of the system it's running on.  Essentially, it's the same kind of database that a Windows/Finder search would use to accelerate a search of an indexed file system.  If you don't want to depend on that index, you can use the find command - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the locate command (if, say, the required database isn't being maintained), you could use the '[`find`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find)' command:

```
find / -type d -name Foo
```

This invocation will find any directory named Foo anywhere under '/' on the filesystem.  Note that this can be very, very slow - if 'locate' is available, that'll probably perform much better.

Answer (score 0):

Exact locate command would be,

```
locate -r ~/".*"MyDir
```

and if needed to refresh db,

```
sudo updatedb
```